# Spring Security with Cucumber - SpringSecurityFilterChainException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cucumber

I am trying to write cucumber tests for my application where I have to send the request as a user.
I am getting this exception on the setup step - **java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.**
I found in the spring documentation too the same thing has to be done as what I am doing. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/setup.html) (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-setup)

Can someone please help?

P.S. the same setup was working in one of my other applications.

This is what I am doing in my step definition class

```
@Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
```

I also have a config class

```
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestExecutionListeners(inheritListeners = false, listeners =
        {DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {
}
```